# Javafx css file fails to load

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I'm having trouble, possibly due to a bug, loading css or any other resource is JavaFX 2.2. As far

```
File xml = new File(getClass().getResource("feed.xml").getFile());
```

Printing the output of the file's path I get :

```
file:/home/bryan/NetBeansProjects/Postr/dist/run916076183/Postr.jar!/postr/feed.xml
```

I'm pretty sure my problem is that exclamation point after the .jar. Any idea why that is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exclamation in a jar url is normal, see the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/JarURLConnection.html) for information.

But you can't load jar resources using the file protocol.  The file protocol is only for loading files from the file system, not for loading resources from jars.

So instead use [getResourceAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) to get a stream for the resource which you then manipulate however you need.

Some JavaFX apis take simple strings as parameters rather than streams or urls, so you can convert the jar resource url to a string using the following pattern:

```
MyApplication.class.getResource("mystyles.css").toExternalForm()
```

Comment: Getting the resource as a stream works for reading the resource, but how might I write back to it once it is modified?